# Malware folder found in Users file - MacOS

Tags: xcode, security, privacy, malware, libphonenumber

Recently I found a hidden file in my Users file (Mac OS) titled the first name of a person.

From the folder titled the first name of the person the file leads to library > developer > Xcode > Derived Data> libphonenumber > Build > Intermediates.noindex >libphonenumber.build > Release > liphonenumber Mac OS.build > Objects normal > x86_64

Then inside this folder approx 20 files with a gcda file extension, such as "NBPhoneMetaData.gcda" "

Apple supported concluded that this is malware, but they are still working on figuring out the source.

Do you think I should be concerned about this being Employer Spyware/Malware?

Thank you,

Anonymous PhD Student

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: This question may be a better fit at https://security.stackexchange.com